# No me funciona Primefaces en eclipse

Tags: java, jsf, eclipse, primefaces, java-ee

He estado tratando de implementar primefaces en un proyecto en eclipse pero no logro hacer que funcione, JSF funciona bien en el proyecto pero cuando intento agregar componentes de primefaces al proyecto el resultado en el navegador es una pagina en blanco, lo único que puedo utilizar con normalidad son los componentes de JSF puro, continuación muestro las configuraciones de eclipse:

[image: componente primefaces en xhtml]

La descarga de primefaces fue con Maven, intente agregando el jar aparte pero tampoco me funciono

[image: configuracion de pom.xml]

y acá muestro la configuración del archivo web.xml
[image: web.xml]

Utilizo Groovy/Grails Tool Suite  3.6.4.RELEASE

Comment: Cambia los pantallazos por el código en texto, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes agregadas las dependencias en el pom.xml, pero asegúrate que maven te las descargo realizando un deploy dependency, ademas para asegurarnos que no sea el theme de boostrap el que dejo de funcionar , cambia el boostrap theme por

```
<dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>  
        <version>1.0.10</version>  
</dependency>
```

También te recomiendo que uses netbeans desde mi punto de vista es mucho mas simple su uso en comparación con eclipse , te dejo un tutorial que me sirvio bastante para aprender JSF 2.0 desde cero

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7mEXB6rEjg&list=PLvimn1Ins-41Dn6vhYzB0Kv90_2eFIdXG

saludos !

Comment: Lo de usar NetBeans/Eclipse/vi porque es mejor editor no sólo es subjetivo sino que no aporta nada a la pregunta.

Answer (score -2):

Hola amigo para mí eclipse es mucho mas robusto, lo que necesitas es agregar la dependencia primefaces y el property .

Propiedad:

```
<properties>
     ......
   <primefaces.version>5.3</primefaces.version>
    ......
</properties>
```

Dependencia:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Saludos!!!

Comment: Si te fijas bien ya tiene la dependencia insertada.